# Responsive Fullscreen img with no cropping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive full-screen image resize to fit the browser window without any cropping occurring.

My starting point so far has been to set `max-width: 100%` on the image so it fills the width of the page. However, if the height of the window changes I need it to switch from `max-width: 100%` to `max-height: 100%` so the image never crops.

The only way I can think to do this is to find out which aspect is larger and then change the CSS to either use `max-width: 100%` or `max-height: 100%` accordingly.

Here's the code so far. It works when resizing by width but not by height:

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {

    resizeImage($("#image"), $(window));

    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        resizeImage($("#image"), $(window));
    });

});

function resizeImage(image, container) {

    var widthRatio = Math.min(image.width() / container.width()),
        heightRatio = Math.min(image.height() / container.height());

    if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
        image.css({
            "max-width" : "none",
            "max-height" : "100%"
        });     
    }
    else {
        image.css({
            "max-width" : "100%",
            "max-height" : "none"
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="ferrari5.jpg" id="image">
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen example:

http://cdpn.io/yAHeb

Comment: Is the container max-width: 100%, and max-height: 100%?  If not you've just shifted the issue from the image to the container.  A http://jsfiddle.net/ would help.

Comment: Your comment has led me to the answer! I thought it was a JS issue but I changed the img tag to be a block level element and set the html and body tags to be 100% height:

http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/yAHeb

If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the container max-width: 100%, and max-height: 100%? If not you've just shifted the issue from the image to the container. A jsfiddle.net would help.

Glad this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with CSS using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I'm not using a background image, its an img tag.